# Kafka Stream contains ^M Character

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

I am streaming twitter feeds from Kafka to spark Streaming.

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);
```

the directKafkaStream is then written as Hadoop files :

```
directKafkaStream.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/abc/sparkstreaming/","",Text.class, IntWritable.class, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

The problem is that all the hadoop files that are generated have a ^M character at the end which is creating problems while loading data to hive.

Please let me know how can I remove these ^M character from hadoop files.

Comment: try using ROW FORMAT LINES TERMINATED BY '^M' in hive table creating script, because ^M is the end of line character in some unix systems.

Comment: I am using json serde to create th hive table as my data file is json format. THe create table does'nt work with ^M as line terminator. OS is Centos 7.